# XSL and entity in CDATA

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<offer>
  <products>
    <product id="1">
                <description>
            <name ><![CDATA[aa&apos;bb]]></name>
            <name2 >aa&apos;bb</name2>
                </description>
    </product>
  </products>
</offer>
```

and xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                                version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="node"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" /> 
<xsl:template match="/offer/products/product" >
<xsl:variable name="title_free" select="description/name"/>
<xsl:variable name="title_free2" select="description/name2"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$title_free"/>
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="$title_free2"/>
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and output of xsltproc

```
$ xsltproc my.xsl my.xml
aa&apos;bb
aa'bb
```

and desired output should be:

```
aa'bb
aa'bb
```

any idea how to achive that?

How to replace entitied in CDATA field into characters?

Comment: AFAIK, the only way you can pull this off using XSLT 1.0 is to save an interim result to a file, then apply a second transformation to the temporary file. (This is assuming you do not have a comprehensive list of entities that can appear in the source XML. )

Answer (score 2):

CDATA is a way to disable the special characters meaning in a well-identified portion of text.  So if you have a lot of those special characters like `<` and `&`, for example a snippet of XML in a code example, you don't have to escape them.

If you write `&` in CDATA it means the character `&` (unlike outside CDATA, where it introduces an entity or a character reference).

So what you ask for is basically an XML parser, which does not exist in XSLT 1.0.  If what you ask is how to replace a string into another (here "`&apos;`" into "`'`") then you can use `replace()` in XSLT 2.0 or any other string manipulation in XSLT 1.0.

But I suspect that what you want, really, is to solve your input data, which happens to contain some double escaping (escaped strings enclosed itself into CDATA).

Comment: i don't want to use replace, becouse i don't want to enlist all available entities.  
the xml is made by my client, so i can't ensure that xml is correct and hasn't entities in CDATA

Comment: is there any option to tell xsltproc to parse CDATA as normal text?

Comment: The example you gave us contains only one.  Do you want to handle others as well?  Which one? `&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&quot`, and `&apos;`?  Even other entities?  Maybe character entities like `&#10;`?  If this is the case, you'd better fix your input.

Comment: If the input should not use CDATA, maybe you can get rid of it (sometimes `sed` is good enough).

Comment: I know that fixing input would be the best option, but you know haw clients are. The just do what they want.  
I cant use any external software - if i could i would use perl and Http:entities  
but this thing must be done in xsltproc :(

Comment: Yes. Sometimes my clients ask me for the XSLT processor to make coffee as well, but, you know... :-)